# Website not found error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I had two websites in magento 2 and I deleted one but it gave me error that

> The website with code root that was requested wasn't found. Verify the
>   website and try again

Now, I am unable to view the admin panel. What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please check your **index.php** file which is available on Magento ROOT. Is there any keyword such as **root** for website code ?

Comment: yes there is root in PARAM_RUN_CODE = 'root'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your **index.php** file with you `website` code like this

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'first.websiteurl.com': // Your first website URL
        $params = $_SERVER; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website_code1'; //You can add your first website code here
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http'); 
        $bootstrap->run($app); 
        break; 
    case 'second.websiteurl.com': // Your second website URL
        $params = $_SERVER; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website_code2'; //You can add your second website code here
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http'); 
        $bootstrap->run($app); 
        break;
    default: 
        $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
        $bootstrap->run($app);
    break; 
}
```

You can find you website code here in backend..

> Stores > Settings > All Stores

Default **index.php** file's content..

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if this will helps you then.

Comment: I am unable to access my admin panel.

Comment: You can comment these both lines..

$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website_code1'; //You can add your first website code here
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';

Comment: After commenting there is another error
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at \/var\/www\/html\/Magento2\/vendor\/zendframework\/zend-http\/src\/PhpEnvironment\/Response.php:114) in \/var\/www\/html\/Magento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Stdlib\/Cookie\/PhpCookieManager.php on line 148"

Comment: What to do now?

Comment: I am still unable to view admin panel

Comment: Which magento version you're using ?

Comment: You can replace your **index.php** file content with Default index.php file's content..

Comment: I've updated that in my answer above

Comment: Thank you it worked.

Comment: You're welcome :)